# XSLT output html tags from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document similar to:

```
<tag>
   <content>adsfasdf<b>asdf</b></content>
</tag>
```

I would like for the XSLT to select the content element and show all of the content:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/tag/content"/>
```

The XSLT is configured to render as HTML. Is there a way that I can get the value-of/copy-of to display the exact content without having to render it?

What I'm looking for is

```
asdfasdf<b>asdf</b>
```

And not:

asdfasdf **asdf**

Comment: Good question, +1. Yes, there is a way to do this -- see the answers by @Nick-Jones and me. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the tag names within the content, I'd recommend something like:

```
<xsl:template match="content//*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which you then can call with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/tag/content"/>
```

Comment: +1 Correct: transforming a node set into **one text node**. Tip: consider the cases for empty elements, attributes and comments (and PI if you want to make it complete)

Comment: stupid question: why not wrap the data in a CDATA block instead? are there any downsides?

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="text() | *"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result against your sample will be:

```
adsfasdf<b>asdf</b>
```

Another approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for the right suggestion to use `copy-of` instead of the `value-of` the poster has in his code. But I think doing `copy-of select="node()"` suffices for the quick and dirty way, no need to name text and element children separately with `text() | *`.

Comment: @Martin, I first wrote `node()`, but then reconsidered :)

Comment: @monksy, sorry, I missed "without having to render it" part.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like for the XSLT to select
>   the content element and show all of
>   the content:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="/tag/content"/>
> ```
>
> The XSLT is configured to render as
>   HTML. Is there a way that I can get
>   the value-of/copy-of to display the
>   exact content without having to render
>   it?
>
> What I'm looking for is
>
> ```
> asdfasdf<b>asdf</b>
> ```
>
> And not:
>
> asdfasdf **asdf**

The answer of @Nick-Jones comes closest to what you want.

Do have a look at the XSLT stylesheet that is part of the **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** for an extensive example how an IE-style collapsible display of any XML document can be produced.